# sort a c++ vector of object pointers by its char key

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector of object pointers, and now I want to sort them according to their char keys. To be more specific, I want to sort the char keys (char c) in "lexicographical order".

For example, suppose I have a vector of objects of POINTERS`<o1, o2, o3, o4, o5>`, and:
`o1->c = 'd'`; `o2->c = 'k'`; `o3->c = 'x'`; `o4->c = 'a'`; `o5->c = 'j'`
then after sorting, the vector should be:
`<o4, o1, o5, o2, o3>`

How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Try looking it up here: [the first result when googling "c++ sort vector"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Comment: actually what I am asking is sorting object POINTERS (I didn't mention that in the original question)...... would that be the same as sorting objects?

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` allows you to pass a custom predicate to it:

```
std::vector<Object*> objects = ...;
std::sort(objects.begin(), 
          objects.end(), 
          [](Object const * x, Object const * y) { return x->c < y->c; });
```

If you have an older compiler that cannot use lambdas, you have to create a class that implements the comparison:

```
struct Foo
{
  bool operator()(Object const * x, Object const * y) const
  {
    return x->c < y->c;
  }
};

std::sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), Foo());
```